# Create a ring body in PhysicsJS

Tags: physics, physicsjs

I am currently working on a project that requires a circular ring shaped body. How can I achieve this? I have tried to use a the `convex-polygon` body with vertices similar to those of a circle but I am getting a `The vertices specified do not match that of a _convex_ polygon.` error. How else can I make a ring shape?

Here is my current attempt:

```
var ring = Physics.body('convex-polygon',{
 x: renderer.width* 0.35,
 y: renderer.height *0.75,
 vertices : [
  { x: -5, y: 0},
  { x: -3, y: 4},
  { x: -4, y: 3},
  { x: 0, y: 5},
  { x: 3, y: 4},
  { x: 4, y: 3},
  { x: 5, y: 0},
  { x: 3, y: -4},
  { x: 4, y: -3},
  { x: 0, y: -5},
  { x: -3, y: -4},
  { x: -4, y: -3}
 ]
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if all you want is a circle, you can use `Physics.body('circle'`. See http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/ the showcase has circles in it

Comment: @rassar I want a circle but with a smaller circle cut out of the center so it is a ring. Is there a way to modify the circle body to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

A ring shaped body is not convex, so that is the reason your model (assuming the vertices are correct) does not work. [This old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483497/is-it-possible-to-create-a-concave-polygon-in-physicsjs) seems to suggest concave objects such as yours are not implemented in Physicsjs. This might have changed, but if not what you want is not possible.

EDIT: The link seems to have been broken. Fixed.